# OutputStream.write() never ends

Tags: java, outputstream

I have a car with a bluetooth interface that I connect to using my android app. Robot is programmed so that when he gets a digit 1-5, he makes an action.
1 - drive forward
2 - drive backward
3 - turn left
4 - turn right
5 - stop
I have 5 buttons in my app. Their events' look like this

```
public void button1(View view){
socket.write("1");
}
```

where socket is the class that holds BluetoothSocket and makes a connection and has write function:

```
public void write(String signal)
{
try
{
OutputStream.write(signal.getBytes());
Log.d("#Signal", " connected");
} catch (IOException e)
{
}
}
```

AND! When I connect, and press for example button that sends 2, robot starts moving backward but I don't get message from line

```
Log.d("#Signal", " connected");
```

So it looks like `write(byte[] buffer)` function never ends it's procedure. After pressing one button, when I try to press another one, it doesn't work. Like OutputStream.write() still tries to write something. I don't know why this happens, any solutions?

Comment: Can you take a thread dump? using ctrl + break in console on Windows.

Comment: @Ferrybig right now I can do nothing, because I don't have this robot I connect to at my place, what do you propose to do after that? btw when I send single int inside like write(1), then it sends it and continue the code

Comment: Do something inside the catch block please, e.g `e.printStackTrace()`;  And, the string "1" isn't the int 1,  it's int 49.  Check [ascii table](https://www.asciitable.com/), and code `System.out.println((int) str.charAt(0));`

Answer (score 1):

Try using flush() function after you call write() like this

```
OutputStream.write(signal.getBytes());OutputStream.flush();
```

Comment: it doesn't work, tried it :(
it won't go to the next line, like write() was some kind of infinite loop
if it could work it would log "#Signal" but it doesn't